# Drupal 7: How to assign each node to different block (or region)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks, drupal-regions

How to assign each node to different block (or region)?

When i add new content and select promote to front page, its every time displayed under "Main page content" block.

I have region "content" and "top-content". "top-content" region has block "Main page content". "content" region has block "myblock". When i add new article or news its allways displayed under same block on my front page.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you need to create a View which grabs nodes you need (you can filter on promoted field, by content type, publication date, field value...). This view must create a block (block display mode), then you can assign this block to whatever region you like in block interface. You can create as many Views as you need, filtering nodes the way you want.

More info :

https://www.drupal.org/project/views

Good luck